# Send mail using own server

Tags: iis, email-server, newsletters

I have a mailing list with my clients e-mail, so it's not SPAM.

The mailing list has around 40,000 e-mails and I use a exe we developed to send all the e-mails with our own server. Since We have Static IP, we've been blacklisted on a couple of lists. Is there any hope to our situation? Or we'll always be spotted as spammers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Ian: outsource it to a company that specializes in sending mass email.

If you simply must do it yourself, make sure:

1. you have reverse DNS setup.  Talk to your ISP about that.
2. have proper SPF records.
3. have a proper one-click unsubscribe link on every email.
4. have your clients add you to their whitelists.
5. send mail in small batches and never too many to any one MX at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think you'd be better off using a hosted service such as mailchimp or campaignmonitor. It's their business to manage white lists for you, as well as unsubscribes etc.

Answer (score 2):

Third vote for outsourcing the email, if you can do so. Dealing with the mess spammers have made of email is too much headache for someone who has other things to do; there are companies which specialize in it. (MailChimp has been good for us.)

If you have to stick to your own solution (maybe it's not your decision?) see also [this previous question on an almost identical topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/176245/emails-from-custom-domain-going-to-spam/176248) (which includes several more things to do to keep your mail from looking like spam).

Answer (score 0):

Which blacklists are you on?

There are some which are policy based i.e. you're on an IP range that isn't supposed to be doing direct to MX delivery.

If you're on one that specifically says it only lists people who have sent spam then respectfully I'd suggest that some of your recipients consider it spam and have reported it as such.